# Как описать граф, где важны только рёбра?

Tags: графы, база-данных

Планирую проект, где будет множество данных о **связях** между очередными двумя узлами, и эти связи и их многочисленные свойства — главная информация, с которой вся работа.

Можно сказать, что есть граф, у которого узлы лишь идентифицируются как-то, чтобы не перепутать, а область интереса это рёбра.

Как бы вы стали описывать и хранить такие данные?

Варианты, которые пока приходят на ум:

1. реляционная БД, таблица нод, таблица связей: `node1id, node2id, json_properties`
2. какая-то специфическая, может, не реляционная бд, заточенная под описание графов?

**Задачи**: хранить, добавлять новые связи, определять, связаны ли две ноды через цепочку связей?

Comment: На ум приходит хэш от двух индексов вершин возвращающий указатель на ребро. Грубо говоря матрица смежности вместо нулей и единиц в которой соответствующий указатель. В дополнении к этому можно хранить индексированный список граней. Также все это очень похоже на полигональную сетку(VV-mesh) из 3D графики. Вот хорошая статья правда на ангийском и там в основном описаны алгоритмы работы для генерации растений, но может найдете что-то полезное так как все равно речь идет о той же структуре данных. http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/smithco.dis2006.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то, как вариант - [neo4j](http://neo4j.org/), [статья на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/152079/)

Comment: Точно.  Спасибо большое!

Comment: @sergiks - нет проблем, удачи в реализации.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно ответ на Ваш вопрос [Язык Анимо](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DrlUT30L1qeRcyjTxGi3Zu5IPUpI4ia3Uu7YHoDYMGE/edit).

Comment: Интересную штуку вы развиваете! Спасибо за ссылку. Исследовали ли вы уже работу Animotron'а под нагрузкой? Поверхностно кажется, что с линейным ростом объёма данных, время вычисления будет расти в геометрической прогрессии.
По сути вопроса - та же neo4j.

Answer (score -2):

Можно попробовать задать переменными PHP координаты и эти переменные в MySQL, или если человек рисует граф в онлайне то просто в PHP

Comment: Нет-нет, речь совсем о другой области. Пролистайте про [графы](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%F0%E0%F4_%28%EC%E0%F2%E5%EC%E0%F2%E8%EA%E0%29).